# How to preview data from COM port with telnet or other windows tool

Tags: serial-port, telnet, peripherals

I would like to see what data come from COM serial port. Is it possible to do it with telnet or other windows tool? And if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HyperTerminal can be used to communicate over/read from a serial port. But there are probably much better, more specialized tools around.

(Note that HyperTerminal is not included in Vista any more, but XP still has it.)